# Writing a function to find the median, of a vector of ints

Tags: c++, function, vector, median

I am trying to write a second function to calculate a vector of integers which is in the main function. My vector is set up like this.

```
int inputinfo;
cout << "\nPlease enter in scores: ";
cout << "\nEnd your input with ctrl-z\n";
vector<int> scores;
    while (cin >> inputinfo)
    {
        scores.push_back(inputinfo);
    }
```

Here is my median equation (which I am not sure is working right). I would like to make a function for median and then call it back to the main function to find the median of the vector.

```
  double median;
  size_t size = scores.size();

  sort(scores.begin(), scores.end());

  if (size  % TWO == 0)
  {
      median = (scores[size / 2 - 1] + scores[size / 2]) / 2;
  }
  else 
  {
      median = scores[size / 2];
  }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you asking how to make and call a function?

Comment: Since your median is a floating-point number, you probably want median = (scores[size/2 - 1] + scores[size/2]) / 2.0; to avoid truncation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether your code fails if thee is none or only one number in the vector. You can fix this using

```
if (size==0) throw "Vector empty";
if (size==1) return scores[0];
```

before the if (size % TWO == 0) line.

Comment: There is no need to make a special case for a size of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Just for a short recap: Median means the middle entry in a sorted list, right?
So you search for

```
//your array has a even size, so you want the middle of it
if (size  % TWO == 0)
{
median = scores[size / 2 - 1];
}
// your array has a odd size, so you average 
else 
{
median = (scores[size / 2 - 1] + scores[size / 2]) / 2;
}
```